# Bluetooth application has stopped

Tags: java, android, android-studio, bluetooth

I imported a project Bluetooth_Chat in Android Studio. Since days I am struggling to make it work. The Emulator starts, but the app stops. I am afraid that I made a mistake while creating  a device. I get this at the end E/Internal: device 'emulator-5554' not found. I googled a mistake but sincerely I got confused because there are many different answers and I don't know which one reffers to my problem.
These are codes impelemented in build.gradle. Can somebody say to me exactly which parameters(including RAM, target, resolution ) should have my virtual device? Thank you

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

```
defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 11
    targetSdkVersion 23
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The emulator also gave me some problems with bluetooth, i suggest to tre on a physical device..
Also post the code that gives you problems if this didn't work

Answer (score 0):

The android emulator does not support Bluetooth, WiFi, NFC, SD card insert/eject, Device-attached headphones, or USB. To test Bluetooth you will have to use a physical device.

[Here](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#starting) is the documentation for the emulator as of 4/12/2016.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11980494)

Comment: Edited to include essential parts.